# Unintended Hebrew characters being read in Python from txt file

Tags: python, utf-8

I'm getting a strange error when I try to read a list from a txt file. It looks like a series of six Hebrew characters. I've read about the *Bush hid the facts*  bug, but setting the encoding to utf-8 on the open() line hasn't resolved the issue for me.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8
g = open("list.txt", "r")
cnt = g.read()
print "%s" % cnt
g.close()
```

Contents of the txt file, which is being generated by a PHP script that reads from a MySQL db, is like:

```
cnt = [('big', '33.333.33.33'), ('human', '33.333.33.33'), ('blue-eyes', '44.444.44.44')]
```

Picture of the error:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W53XO.png]

If I copy a snippet of the list from the txt file and include it in the .py script, there is no error. This isn't practical for my purpose though as the complete list is > 50 MB in size.

I really appreciate any help at all.

Comment: I do not think that these are Hebrew characters at all. IMHO, they are some "icons" that bear some resemblance to Hebrew.

Comment: When I copy and paste your code I'm also getting `invalid syntax` and `statement expected, found BAD_CHARACTER` warning in Pycharm, but when I retype it from scratch it works. You should try that.

Comment: What text editor are you using for this? It might be worth trying to open the file in something else, because the only thing I can think of is that there's junk preceding your `cnt = g.read()` line that's being masked somehow. Copy pasting your code worked fine for me.

Comment: Are you sure the PHP script generates UTF-8 ? Have you tried decoding the string in Python using other codes (e.g. cp1255)? A minimal sample of list.txt would help

Comment: @MostlyHarmless I've gotten the error downloading the txt file directly from my server and copy pasting the txt into Notepad and Notepad++. Any suggestions for an alternative?

Comment: @Will I'm not convinced the issue's in the `.txt` file, it would be junk in the `.py` file causing that kind of syntax error. In terms of other editors to try, Python's IDLE is likely already installed, otherwise I'm a fan of Emacs (`M-x hexl-mode` would be useful to see if there's any junk in the file in the form of non-printing chars). Does the python script only have issues with the one txt file or reading in any files?

Comment: @MostlyHarmless It seems to be with this text file only. In a later version of the script, I use .open(), .read(), and .write() with w+ successfully, as long as the cnt list is included in the .py script itself.

Comment: @Amnon I tried doing g.encode(encoding='utf-8') in between the lines where I'm opening and reading the file, and those same characters come up -- though this time on the .encode() line, per this image: http://i.imgur.com/x4aTYA0.png

Comment: Those characters are definitely not Hebrew.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I took a semester of Hebrew, and they sure look a lot like tov, he, and resh to me.

Comment: @Will Hm... that new image makes me a lot more confident that the issue is with your python script. Can you try running this code in a python terminal (with fixes for file names and my inability to put newlines/indent in comments): `with open('ascorely.py','rb') as fin:\n  for line in fin:\n    print map(chr,line)` - a hex editor would also do the trick, but this should make any junk in the file stand out.

Comment: @Will I took being Jewish and raised as such, and they're either unacceptably-mangled Hebrew characters or they're somewhere close to `╗` (Alt+187) and `┐` (Alt+191).